# Flask Sqlite3 NOT NULL constraint failed user.password

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I'm getting a `IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: user.password` when I try to add the first user into my `sqlite3` database. I'm not sure what about where I'm using `user.password` is causing this error. I don't get the error after manually adding the first user into the db. Any suggestions?

```
@classmethod
def create_user(cls, email, password, username, **kwards):
    email = email.lower()

    try:
        cls.select().where(
            (cls.email == email) | (cls.username == username)
        ).get()
    except cls.DoesNotExist:
            user = cls(username = username, email = email)
            user.password = user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user
    else:
        raise Exception("User with that email exists already")
```

Comment: If I were to guess, I would say `user.set_password(password)` does not return a password, but returns `None` which you are then assigning to `user.password`. Just do `user.set_password(password)` without the `user.password = ` part.

Comment: I believe @BurhanKhalid is exactly right here.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid that was correct. you should put it as the answer.